# Reboot-required – where to check?

Tags: reboot

It is quite easy to check if the currently running system needs a restart. You check the existence of either `/var/run/reboot-required` or `/run/reboot-required`. But which one will also work tomorrow? On my system, `/var/run` is just a link to `/run`, so I guess there is a history here that explains things. Is it safe to just test `/run/reboot-required`?

Comment: That's what I do `cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs`

Comment: A safer way is to `cat /var/run/reboot*`. Sometimes the reboot hint is not in `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for reboot-required and maybe checking the contents of reboot-required.pkgs has been the standard way of doing things on Debian / Ubuntu for quite a while.  We're doing it at work with a fleet of 100's of VM's using icinga and SNMP extensions, never seen an issue with it..

Edited to say:  We check /run/reboot-required not /var/run/reboot-required...  /var/run is a symlink to /run..

- Chris H.